# Recommendations for Antennas installation with Steep slopes

Tags: antenna, antenna-construction, hf, nvis

I have a property that I am trying to figure out the right antenna setup for.

**Transmission Goals**
North of this property is 900 miles to communicate 80M or 40M.

Also want to communicate to another location with the hill blocking to SE so this is the NVIS target, SE over a mountain to the next valley ~60miles

**Antennas available**
I have 3 antennas at different heights see table.  Two of them run downhill angles to a tree (870 feet) about 20 feet above street level (856 feet).

- 1x Hustler 5BTV Vertical with radials (position#1 @ weight room)
- 1x Chameleon in a NVIS configuration (position#2 @ weight room and Tree above lower street)
- 1x Windom40 OCF (Dining room, position #3 to tree (same tree) below weight room above street level bottom of hill)

**House Descriptive**
All are coming off of decks which are named after rooms in the second column (House is 3 levels hanging off a hillside).

North facing, downslope property in a Canyon about midway up canyon wall.

[image: North side of House from street looking up]

[image: Property layout with Antenna locations]

Angles for the property are as follows...

House has 3 livable levels at Downward Slopes of 84%,59%,56%;

Laser range finder measured 53 degrees, 32 degrees, 29 degrees up from the street at bottom of hill to the decks described in table.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!  What is your goal for your antenna system?

Comment: I am looking for a vertical covering a number of bands, all good except 80M is poor.  So would like a separate 80M and also want to achieve a solid NVIS antenna.

Comment: @spreckoak Please edit your question to include that. Readers shouldn't have to read the comments to see the complete picture. I have added the NVIS tag for you. :-)

Comment: What are the approximate dimensions of your property? I don't grasp the relationship of those angles to the lengths and layout of your land. A drawing inserted in your question might help! In fact if it were detailed enough, someone might even offer to model it for you. :-)

Comment: Downvoted because your question lacks sufficient details and the link is broken. (Add the requested details, and I'll undo that :-). Plus, you will probably receive a more helpful answer.

Comment: Can you put a photo or two in your question?

Comment: Sorry, but you didn't quite answer my question about your goals.  Obviously you're looking to make local contacts or you wouldn't have mentioned NVIS.  Are you also interested in making contacts out further than 1000 km (600 miles) or so?  And why do you say you want a multi-band vertical?  Is that because you're looking for one antenna to cover most bands?  We could give you better recommendations if you would tell us more.

Comment: The OP Posted the antennas he is using, including 80m. Also included goals both local and long distance to the mile. Posted the possible issues he is having with shape of property and antenna location. Lastly, he is on a steep hillside and asking about possible issues due to sloping earth in relationship to the antenna types he is using. Woulndt it be easier to provide an answer on what antenna types would work best on steep slopes? OR Provide helpful data or info related to Antenna types in relation to angle of sloping hillsides? OR Provide helpful info on Antennas that are not affected by sl

Answer (score 2):

You are *not* going to get a decent NVIS signal on 80 meters with a vertical. (The exception might be an antenna like an inverted-L, with much of the top horizontal.)

### Dipole

A far better choice would be a dipole (either horizontal or inverted-vee), no more than λ/4 high. A balanced dipole does not need an RF ground system to be efficient, but an inverted-L does.

I had an inverted V dipole supported at 65' and the ends about 15' to 20' high. It worked very well indeed.

### Horizontal loop

A horizontal loop is another option; However, it requires multiple supports at a sufficient height above the earth to minimize losses in the ground underneath it.

Beware of the common myth that the lower the antenna, the better it works as an NVIS antenna. On the contrary, your signal will be weaker and lack the coverage that a higher horizontal antenna will.